# Determine if Cobb-Douglas function is a contraction map

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f:(\mathbb{R}^2, d) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},d) $ be a function (usually called in economics Cobb-Douglas Production function ) defined by $ f(x,y)= \lambda x^\alpha  y^{1-\alpha} \quad , \alpha \in (0,1)$ and $d$ is usual metric $\rho_2$.

How can one determine if f is a contraction, i.e $\forall u,v \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ is there a number $\beta \in (0,1) $ s.t $ d(f(u), f(v)) \leq \beta d(u,v)$?
I could not find a trick to pass from distances in the range to the distances in the domain?

Comment: Can you add context?  I don't think it is a contraction--the usual definition of a contraction is for functions (or relations) $T:X\rightarrow X$, or from a space to itself, and the cobb-douglas is $R^2\rightarrow R$. Are you trying to  use a contraction to prove something else?

Comment: No I just want to know if cobb douglas is a contraction

Comment: Well, I don't think it is, since you still have the dimension problem.  But here's a cheat. Set $x=y$, then if $\lambda <1$ you have a contraction on the restricted space.